# how to write a regex for negative or positive decimal values by using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, angular6

```js
 onlyDecimalNumberKey(event) {
    
    const pattern = /^-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$/;
    let inputChar = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);
    if (event.keyCode != 8 && !pattern.test(inputChar)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    
  }
```

```html
<input click="onlyDecimalNumberKey($event)">
```

i have one input field it should be to allow in the first place either minus or nothing(not plus character). from second place on words it need to allow digits or dot like below.

ex:-
-0.234,
12.0344,
-123.0042,
1.345,
-2.0034,
1234.0344,

Comment: i tried that one already but it is not allowing minus(+) and dot(.)

Comment: Your regex seems to be working fine. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

commented regex is working fine!

```js
function onlyDecimalNumberKey() {
    const pattern = /^-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$/;
    let inputChar = event.target.value;
    
    if (event.keyCode != 8 && pattern.test(inputChar)) {
      console.log(inputChar, ": valid");
      event.preventDefault();
    } else {
    console.log(inputChar, ": invalid")
    }
    
  }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <input onChange="onlyDecimalNumberKey()">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not working, In this i am able to enter the all values(digits, alphabets, special characters). but it need to allow only Numbers and dot(.), and in the first place should be either minus(-) or nothing.